# Placing media queries in the app.scss file in Foundation 6 isn't working

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation-6

I'm new to Foundation 6. I want to make the heading text on my web page smaller when the viewport is medium or smaller.

I understand to make a media query, the css for it goes in the app.scss file, just below the @import section.  My code follows the new approach for media queries in Foundation 6 and looks like this:

```
.head {
  @include breakpoint(medium down) {
     font-size: 2rem; 
     }
}
```

However, after I save my page and app.scss file and then refresh my browser, there's no change when I make my page smaller.  Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Hey... I figured it out!  (Whew).  Never mind.

Answer (score -1):

I did my own mixins so that you can tinker those little fixes without limitation. you should try it.

```
//Breakpoints *include
@mixin bp-xl {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1400px){
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin bp-l {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin bp-m {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin bp-s {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin bp-xs {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Then all you do is for example:

```
p {
font-size: 18px;
@include bp-s{font-size:22px;};

@include bp-m{font-size:24px;};

@include bp-xl{font-size:32px;};
}
```

**¡You can also create as much rules as you need!**
Hope you like it :D

Comment: Dear Matias,                                                                                                     I don't know if my response went through the first time, so I wanted to thank you very much for responding to my question; I appreciate it.  Sincerely, Steve

Comment: So great that u find it useful. +1 so that others may also benefit from it.